# rotate text vertically in pentaho report 5.4 version

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am using pentaho report designer. I want to rotate text by 90 degree in label.How to do that if any body knows please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called rotation in style section where you can specify the rotation between -90 to 90 based on your requirement.

Comment: but this property is not available in pantaho 5.4 version .Is there any other way to achive this?